# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in .net 6

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

My front end is in react and the urls is https://qa.example.com

My .net 6 api hosted as https://api.example.com

When i am get data from my react app using api it's give me below error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/Sharepoint' from origin 'https://qa.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have also set rules in my .net 6 application, but still i am facing this issues.

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_MyAllowSubdomainPolicy";

```
        //Enable Cors
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              policy =>
                              {
                                  policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000",
                                      "https://qa.example.com",
                                      "https://example.com")
                                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowAnyOrigin()                                      
                                  .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                              });
        });
```

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

Comment: I find you use  `WithOrigins` and `AllowAnyOrigin` together. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS in Asp.Net Core, what we need is [the order of the middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order).

UseCors, UseAuthentication, and UseAuthorization must appear in the order shown.

```
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
// app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseRouting();
// app.UseRateLimiter();
// app.UseRequestLocalization();
// app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// app.UseSession();
// app.UseResponseCompression();
// app.UseResponseCaching();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();
```